# Android - set background based on variable

Tags: android, button

I want to set the background of a button based on a variable. The view cannot be applied to 
int, but how can I solve the problem?

`String picture = db.getName();
Button cal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cal);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(picture, "drawable",  this.getPackageName());
cal.setBackgroundDrawable(resID);`

Comment: use switch Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use a conditional test to test the value of the variable you are using.

I presume from the code snippet that the variable that controls which background to apply is the `String picture = db.getName();` line. So you would take that variable and do tests to it.

Like so:

```
String picture = db.getName();
Button cal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cal);
Drawable resId;

if(picture.equals("tree") {
    resId = R.drawable.tree_image;
} else if(picture.equals("light") {
    resId = R.drawable.light_image;
}

cal.setBackgroundDrawable(resId);
```

However, you can also name your images inside your drawable folder the same as whatever `db.getName()` will equal. Then using your code you can get the drawable. **NOTE YOU NEED TO GET A DRAWABLE NOT AN ID** I see that you are getting an int id value which is not acceptable in the method `setBackgroundDrawable()`

To use your method you would simply do this:

```
String picture = db.getName();
Button cal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cal);
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(picture, "drawable",  this.getPackageName()); // This will return an integer value stating the id for the image you want.

Drawable drawablePic = getResources().getDrawable(resID); //This will get you the image in the form of a drawable to be set in the method below.
cal.setBackgroundDrawable(drawablePic); //Now we set the drawable image to the view.
```

You can use either method. The second one all depends on how you have your images named inside your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
call switch method in where your variable change 


 switch (YourVariable) {
            case 1: 
             // set your code to determine which button background should be here 
                     break;
            case 2: 
            // set your code to determine which button background should be here 
                     break;
            case 3: 
          // set your code to determine which button background should be here 
                     break;

            default:
          // make your default code here  
                         break;
```